# WPF MahApps.Metro AnimatedSingleRowTabControl FontSize

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, mahapps.metro

How do I change the font size of the tabs when using the MahApps.Metro AnimatedSingleRowTabControl.

When using a normal TabControl, my theme TabItem (based on MetroTabItem) overrides the fontsize but this does not work for the animated single row tab control. I tried setting the fontsize property on the control in the XAML and this didn't work either.

Regards
Alan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following, setting the header font size to whatever value you want:

```
<metro:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl>
    <metro:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type metro:MetroTabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type metro:MetroTabItem}}">
            <Setter Property="HeaderFontSize" Value="24"/>
        </Style>
    </metro:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</metro:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl>
```

Comment: This works great when I have it in the main XAML markup but when I try to transfer this to my theme file, I keep getting exceptions. Can you show me the correct entries to put into a theme file. Thx

Comment: You should be able to just use the <Style> definition of this in a skin or theme xaml file.  Be sure to include the metro namespace.

Answer (score 3):

You can also define the following in the `Application.Resources` your App.xaml:

```
<system:Double x:Key="TabItemFontSize">16</system:Double>
```

Controls.TabControl.xaml makes use of it as follows:

```
<Setter Property="Controls:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize"
        Value="{DynamicResource TabItemFontSize}" />
```

Comment: Where do you add this?  Inside my Application.Resources I have a resourceDictionsry and inside that I have ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries.  Everywhere I try to paste <system:Double VS keeps underlining it (prefix system is not defined) then I capitalized the S and put it inside the merged dictionaries and it says (Double is not supported in WPF project)

Comment: Put in after </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> but before </ResourceDictionary>.

Comment: No luck, it still says the namespace profix System is not defined.

Comment: Add xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" and make sure it's "<system:Double ..."